# Azure function EventGridTrigger recieves strange events from EventGrid

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I have an Azure Function using an `EventGridTrigger` and created an event subscription for it in my EventGrid Domain Topic.

In the event subscription, I've filtered event types on `Service.Event.Foo`, these works fine and my function executes. My question is about the other events which also trigger it to execute, mainly the two below events:

`Microsoft.Resources.ResourceActionSuccess`

`Microsoft.Resources.ResourceWriteSuccess`

Why are these not filtered by my event type? Looking at the look it seems it related to something happening inside the Event Grid, logging the data I get a lot of stuff with authorization and claims and my own identity principle that I'm logged into Azure with.

What are causing these events?

Why don't my event-type filter remove them?

How can I get rid of them, other than filtering them directly in my Azure Function?

Edit:
I can add that these event's do not appear in my deadletter storage, there only my `Service.Event.Foo` appears if i shut down my function.

Comment: Did you subscribed for Resource Group and sharing the same event handler endpoint? Those event types related to the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-resource-groups, have a look at other properties of these event messages such as *subject*, *topic*, *resourceUri* and *operationName*

Comment: Ahh ok, thank you, talked to my colleague and had been fooling around with cloud shell trying to setup an event subscription he might have accidentally created the subscription on the function for the resource group, i was only looking at the subscriptions on my own event grid!

Comment: @RomanKiss I think I’ll just copy your comment and put it in an answer. Or maybe you should :)

Comment: @CodeMonkey Hi, if you solve the problem. You can mark Roman's suggestion as the answer of this question, this will help others quickly find where the question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you subscribed for Resource Group and sharing the same event handler endpoint? 
Those event types related to the [Azure Event Grid event schema for resource groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-resource-groups).

Have a look at other properties of these event messages such as *subject*, *topic*, *resourceUri* and *operationName*.